# Find all critical points and determine whether each is a local max, min or saddle point

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $f(x, y) = y^2 x-y x^2+xy $

Find all critical point of f and determine
whether each is a local maximum, minimum, or saddle point.

Using partial differentation i have found the critcal points to be $(1/3,-1/3)$ $(0,0)$ $(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$.

How will I then find whether the points are a maximum minimum or a saddle point?

Comment: Using Hessian Matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to 2-D space, which used from the second derivative, You can use Hessian Matrix here. To find more information see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

This can be done by determinant of the hessian matrix. If it is $D$, we have:

> 1. If ${\displaystyle D(a,b)>0}$  and ${\displaystyle f_{xx}(a,b)>0}$ then ${\displaystyle (a,b)}$ is a local minimum of $f$.
> 2. If ${\displaystyle D(a,b)>0}$ and ${\displaystyle f_{xx}(a,b)<0}$ then ${\displaystyle (a,b)}$ is a local maximum of $f$.
> 3. If ${\displaystyle D(a,b)<0}$ then ${\displaystyle (a,b)}$ is a saddle point of $f$.
> 4. If ${\displaystyle D(a,b)=0}$ then the second derivative test is inconclusive, and the point $(a, b)$ could be any of a minimum, maximum or saddle point.